# ASP.NET MVC authentication only works when debugging on Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC ASP.NET application set with "Individual user accounts". The log in and register features only works when debugging in Chrome. When i run without debugging on any browser including Chrome, i get redirected to the login page when attempting to register or log in.

In my web.config class i have this

```
 <system.web>
<authentication mode="None" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
```

Any idea as to whats going on?

Comment: Try to clean the cache of the browser, clean the solution and make a rebuild. If it is not working try to close and reopen vs. If none of them works give here some more info where you might think the problem is coming from etc.

Comment: What database are you using? LocalDB (Visual Studio's lightweight version of MSSQL Express)? If you are using the LocalDB, I've noticed that this does not work outside of debugging, possibly because it's just meant for development and relies on VS to run.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before, and it's related to cookies and session state, try to run your solution without debugger in google incognito if it ran successfully, then clear your browser cache from settings (cookies).

for OWIN itself, make sure to update all of your nuget packages, this should solve the problem.